# Database connection and querying in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Okay, so after about an hour of searching through the web, I'm still having issues trying to create a local DB connection in ASP.net.

I need to create a connection to a local database file, and then simply loop through each record in a table. I'm not sure which file extension to use here (.aspx, .vbhtml, .cshtml?)

This is what I currently have from this [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/website/webpages_database.asp) tutorial,

```
' Create local connection to DB file
@{
var db = Database.Open("Properties.mdf"); 
var query = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Properties"); 
}

    <div id="pagewrap">

        ' Loop through records
        @foreach(var row in query)
        {

        <p>@row.StreetAddress</p> 
        <p>@row.City</p> 
        <p>@row.State</p> 

        }

    </div>
```

I'm currently getting a `Connection string "Properties.mdf" was not found.` error when running the above code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Properties.mdf in your app_data folder?

Answer (score 1):

That is because "Properties.mdf" is not a connection string. The `mdf` file cannot be opened just like this on its own - it needs a proper sql server database service. Exemplary connection string could look like this

```
var db = Database.Open("Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=Properties.mdf;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes");
```

Although you need to have sql server installed (in this case your sql server instance would be called `SQLExpress`). and the connection string highly depends on what version of SQL Server you want to connect to.

Please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article.